# Can't create two mysql pods on k8s

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

I'm trying to run two mysql pods in one cluster.
First mysql pod uses hdd as storage. Second mysql pod uses ssd as storage.The first pod works. But the second pod falls into "crash loop back off".

I make the two pods with using two .yaml files. These files are here.

deployMysqlHdd.yaml(The first pod. This works.)

```
---
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: local-hdd-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysqlpersistentvolume
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1000Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-hdd-storage
  local:
    path: /k8sLocalStorage/mysql
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: disktype
          operator: In
          values:
          - hdd
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysqlvolumeclaim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1000Gi
  storageClassName: local-hdd-storage
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-nodeport
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: mysql-port
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
      nodePort: 3306
  selector:
    name: mysql
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysql-auth
type: Opaque
stringData:
  password: **********
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysqldeployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mysql
        image: mysql
        env:
          - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mysql-auth
                key: password
        volumeMounts:
          - name: mysqlvolumes
            mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
        - name: mysqlvolumes
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mysqlvolumeclaim
---
```

deployMysqlSSD.yaml(The second pod. This doesn't work.)

```
---
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: intelnuc-local-mysql-storageclass
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: intelnuc-mysql-persistentvolume
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 500Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: intelnuc-local-mysql-storageclass
  local:
    path: /k8sNodeData/mysql
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: disktype
          operator: In
          values:
          - ssd
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: intelnuc-mysql-persistentvolumeclaim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 500Gi
  storageClassName: intelnuc-local-mysql-storageclass
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: intelnuc-mysql-nodeport
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: intelnuc-mysql-port
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
      nodePort: 3307
  selector:
    name: mysql-high-resource
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: intelnuc-mysql-auth
type: Opaque
stringData:
  password: ***********
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: intelnuc-mysql-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: intelnuc-mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: intelnuc-mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: intelnuc-mysql
        image: mysql
        env:
          - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: intelnuc-mysql-auth
                key: password
        volumeMounts:
          - name: intelnuc-mysql-volumes
            mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
        - name: intelnuc-mysql-volumes
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: intelnuc-mysql-persistentvolumeclaim
---
```

And a result of `kubectl describe pod` about the second pod is here.

```
Name:         intelnuc-mysql-deployment-9685c849-mvg4p
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         intelnuc/192.168.1.10
Start Time:   Sat, 19 Sep 2020 06:37:16 +0000
Labels:       name=intelnuc-mysql
              pod-template-hash=9685c849
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.244.2.23
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.2.23
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/intelnuc-mysql-deployment-9685c849
Containers:
  intelnuc-mysql:
    Container ID:   docker://8bbe74e6d90cce313be9e8708319470a85a25a98742bc0472bcda193be91d277
    Image:          mysql
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://mysql@sha256:e1bfe11693ed2052cb3b4e5fa356c65381129e87e38551c6cd6ec532ebe0e808
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Sat, 19 Sep 2020 06:38:13 +0000
      Finished:     Sat, 19 Sep 2020 06:38:13 +0000
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Sat, 19 Sep 2020 06:37:43 +0000
      Finished:     Sat, 19 Sep 2020 06:37:43 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  3
    Environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:  <set to the key 'password' in secret 'intelnuc-mysql-auth'>  Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /var/lib/mysql from intelnuc-mysql-volumes (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-6m588 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  intelnuc-mysql-volumes:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  intelnuc-mysql-persistentvolumeclaim
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-6m588:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-6m588
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  <unknown>          default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/intelnuc-mysql-deployment-9685c849-mvg4p to intelnuc
  Normal   Pulling    10s (x4 over 63s)  kubelet, intelnuc  Pulling image "mysql"
  Normal   Pulled     7s (x4 over 60s)   kubelet, intelnuc  Successfully pulled image "mysql"
  Normal   Created    7s (x4 over 60s)   kubelet, intelnuc  Created container intelnuc-mysql
  Normal   Started    7s (x4 over 60s)   kubelet, intelnuc  Started container intelnuc-mysql
  Warning  BackOff    6s (x5 over 56s)   kubelet, intelnuc  Back-off restarting failed container
```

I thought the Service of NodePort setting on the second pod is wrong, and I have tried to change the settings sometime. But I could't solve this problem.

I'd like to know where to fix it.

---

Additional information.

A result of `kubectl logs <podname>` is here.

```
2020-09-20 07:33:20+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.21-1debian10 started.
2020-09-20 07:33:20+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-09-20 07:33:20+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.21-1debian10 started.
2020-09-20 07:33:20+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2020-09-20T07:33:20.840302Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21) initializing of server in progress as process 43
2020-09-20T07:33:20.841379Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010457] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2020-09-20T07:33:20.841384Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
2020-09-20T07:33:20.841423Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-09-20T07:33:20.841495Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.21)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Comment: what is the logs for your second pod?

Comment: The logs above is the second pod log. I didn't post the logs for first pod. Because the first pod works normally.

Comment: You have only posted the manifests. not the logs. Use `kubectl logs <podname>` but directly when the pod has started - since it is crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run `kubectl logs <podname>` according to Jonas's comment. And I see the cause of the problem. It works since I empty the mysql data directory. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think, the issue is because the label of the 2nd Service do not match with label of the deployment. Could you please change it and try again.

Like instead of selector of service label "name: mysql-high-resource", try using "name: intelnuc-mysql".

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: intelnuc-mysql-nodeport
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: intelnuc-mysql-port
    port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
    nodePort: 3307
  selector:
    name: mysql-high-resource
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried using "name: intelnuc-mysql". But it doesn't work. The second container still falls into "crash loop back off".